# UWP: How to subscribe to LayoutUpdated in C++WinRT

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt

I am trying to subscribe to event LayoutUpdated in UWP C++WinRT app. I have following code

code behind .h

```
event_token layoutUpdatedToken{};
void MyLayoutUpdated(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);
```

code behind .cpp

```
FamilyValuePropControl::FamilyValuePropControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    layoutUpdatedToken = LayoutUpdated({ this, &FamilyValuePropControl::MyLayoutUpdated });
}

void FamilyValuePropControl::MyLayoutUpdated(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e)
{
    // do something here
}
```

With this code, I am getting the following error

Error   C2664   'void (const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable &,const winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'const T' to 'const winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs &'

I see that LayoutUpdated takes in EventHandler which has a operator

```
auto operator()(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, impl::param_type<T> const& args) const;
```

which has second parameter as impl::param_type const& args. So what should be the event handler signature? I see all examples with C# which use RoutedEventArgs. So not able to understand what should be the signature for C++WinRT. Any help?

Comment: The delegate's type is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.layoutupdated) as `EventHandler<IInspectable>`, meaning that your function signature would need to be `void d(IInspectable const&, IInspectable const&)` (or something that can be called with two arguments of type `IInspectable*`). [This comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/955#issuecomment-469516966) is somewhat enlightening.